# Confused with Big O Notation

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, big-o

So I get that the first for loop runs O(n) times, then inside that it runs 3 times, then 3 times again. How do I express this at big O notation though? Then do the 2 print statements matter? How do I add them to my big-o expression? Thanks, really confused and appreciate any help.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                    printf("%d", arr[x]);
                   }
                printf("\n");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O notation are always defined as a function of input size - n. Big O gives the upper limit of total time taken to run that module. Because your inner "for" loops are always run 3*3 =9 times irrespective of the input size of n - there are still considered as constant time in Big O calculations

```
Time Complexity = O(n+9+constantTimeToPrint) = O(n)
```

Comment: so I can essentially just ignore the 9+printf parts?

Comment: Well, you are actually not ignoring it but by definition O(n + constant) = O(n)

Answer (score 2):

`O(n)` is linear time, so any `k * O(n)` where `k` is a constant (like in your example) is also linear time and is just expressed as `O(n)`. Your example has `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The two inner loops are constant, so it's still O(n). constant factors don't matter, the runtime varies only with the input size.